# Steps for Creating a jsp application with SpringHibernate framework?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller

I used to hardcode my JSP applications and I have never used Spring framework before, I would like to get an overview of how to create a JSP app, I already have spring hibernate set up in eclipse:
How to configure web.xml?

Comment: That is a long subject. If you want to use Spring + Hibernate for web applications maybe you can start reading SpringMVC tutorials: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaBeat has some good tutorials on Spring, in particular some with Spring and Hibernate I recommend you check out:

[Spring Framework Tutorials](http://www.javabeat.net/2013/03/spring-tutorials/)

[Spring and Hibernate ORM Framework Integration](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/integrating-spring-framework-with-hibernate-orm-framework/)